# How do I extend if logic from skipping particular slides to specific portions of a Beamer frame?

Tags: beamer, conditionals

I have the following working structure for excluding particular lecture slides from the article form of a lecture:

```
\documentclass[11pt,handout]{beamer}

\newif\iflecture

\lecturetrue

% Next three lines for article form of presentation

\lecturefalse 

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\iflecture

...frames for just the lecture and not the article form

\fi
```

remaining frames for both.

Can this logic be extended to within a single frame?

```
\begin{frame}

...content for both lecture and article, a problem for example

end article content here

...remaining content just for lecture

\end{frame}
```

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. For code-blocks indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui. Also, by convention we do not write "thanks", as this is was the voting and assigning ticks is for, or sign our names, s they appear at the bottom of the post.

Comment: To answer your question: yes! If you put `\iflecture...\fi` anywhere in your document it will only display that code block if `\lectureture`. You can also do `\iflecture<code when true>\else<code when false>\fi`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want certain material to appear only when the file is typeset as a lecture, with `\lectureture`, then you only need to surround it with

```
\iflecture <lecture only material>...\fi
```

Similarly, for material that is not for the lecture use:

```
\iflecture\else <article only material>...\fi
```

Of course, you can also combine these:

```
\iflecture <lecture only material>
\else <article only material>\fi
```

Another useful construct is that you can pass different options to beamer, or to other packages, using `\PassOptionsToClass`. Here is a full MWE:

```
\newif\iflecture
\lecturefalse   % uncomment if typesetting as an article
%\lecturetrue   % uncomment if typesetting as a lecture

\iflecture\else
  \PassOptionsToClass{11pt,handout}{beamer}
\fi

\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

  \iflecture
    \begin{frame}{Lecture only frame}
    A framed lecture
    \end{frame}
  \fi

  \begin{frame}
    ...content for both lecture and article, a problem for example
    \iflecture\else article content here\fi

    \iflecture ...remaining content just for lecture\fi
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```